# Phonegap Builder with Cordova SMS Plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I would like to implement a App in Phonegap with the Adobe Phonegap Builder under http://build.phonegap.com. And I would like to use the Plugin https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/2420 to send SMS.

In my config.xml stay:

```
 <gap:plugin name="com.cordova.plugins.sms" version="0.1.2" />
```

The Adobe PhoneGap Builder shows this plugin as integrate plugin.

My next action was to download and add the /www/sms.js from https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin/tree/48d9630  and include this in the index.html

Then I add to a JavaScript function like the example on Git:

```
var message = "Testing SMS by sending it to ";
var options = {
    replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
    android: {
        intent: 'INTENT'  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
        //intent: '' // send SMS without open any other app
    }
 };

var success = function () { 
    alert('Message sent successfully'); 
};

var error = function (e) { 
    alert('Message Failed:' + e); 
};

sms.send("MY Handy number", "sms", options, success, error);
```

In a other Post I found that replace

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');
```

with

```
var exec = cordova.exec
```

can help, but it do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok .
i have "fix" it.

there must the first include js, in this order.
Also its important that the file sms.js is not exists.

In the config.xml
you must put in:

an that is it. :)